# Refresh template using templateUrl in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, templates, caching

I have web app that is very slow (there are few http connections that are very slow even on localhost) so reloading the page when template is change is painful, is there a way to refresh the directive's template file fetch using templateUrl from console?

Comment: Hope this links helps https://jsfiddle.net/dhanrajv/L5g966nt/

Comment: @Raj this don't work: `function refresh(name) { $.get(name).then(function(html) { $('.ng-scope:eq(0)').injector().get('$templateCache').put(name, html); }); }`, I need to use templateUrl, I don't want to change the app code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which build do you use, but for example with `gulp`, you can use the `gulp-angular-templatecache` that will put in cache all your templates.

So each time your app requests a template, it will fetch in the cache first.

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/sanderhahn/8595191) that can help you.